# Как импортировать tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, импорт, tensorflow

Появилась возможность использоваться tensorflow-gpu. Сделал все как положенно (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306862/how-to-use-tensorflow-gpu). Но при импорте библиотеки выдает

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Как к GPU версии обращаться? Мне для начала надо сделать банальные вещи, и могу работать на cpu, но все же, если есть возможность, надо ее реализоваться

Comment: Сейчас не нужно скачивать отдельно `tensorflow-gpu`. Устанавливайте так `pip install tensorflow`.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, а cuda и т.п. нужно было хоть устанавливать? По умолчанию будет gpu использоваться?

Comment: Нужно, смотрите [здесь](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu). Должно по умолчанию использовать gpu.

Comment: pip uninstall tensorflow  
pip install tensorflow-gpu==<version>  
После этого должно импортиться, если нет найдите папку питона, найдите в site-packages tensorflow